# OpenGL Is High Efficiency For Large Number of Vertices Necessarily Highly Efficient For Low Numbers of Vertices

Tags: opengl-es

To test my program, I rendered hundreds of times more vertices than the program will ever actually have (about 5000 vertices total for the exaggerated version). The exaggerated program lagged when using GL_FLOAT and did not when using GL_SHORT. What I'm wondering is if this optimization (and other optimizations) actually uses less energy than using GL_FLOAT for low numbers of vertices (since I read that some GPUs need to emulate integer functionality and I'm not sure if the increased speed is just because the float version passed some kind of memory limit (which it seems like it did, because lag immediately ended upon removing an exact number of vertices in the float version))). I'm using OpenGL es 1.1 right now, but advice for any version would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point math is generally slower due to their nature than fixed point math.

Mobile GPUs may be able to process many more fixed point operations at a time than floating points and there is added pipelined latency for floating points so the effective GFLOPs are much lower than peak figures. But publicly-available GPU details from manufacturers are scarce.

The biggest performance difference however is most likely because your vertices take twice as much memory and bandwidth when stored as GL_FLOAT compared to GL_SHORT.

Comment: @Bálint - this is ES on mobile GPUs.

Comment: @Bálint Floats are much slower. For example on a Nehalem i7 integer addition (ADD) execute in 1 cycle with **1 cycle latency**, FADD executes in 1 cycle with **3 cycles latency**. Which means the processor **could** do something else but has to wait 2 cycles before using the result **if it needs it right now**. This latency is often higher in GPUs to reach higher clocks & pack more (simpler) cores. They try to hide the latency through parallelism but integers & fixed points are still much faster in real world situations.

http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf